# How can I programmatically import orders into Magento?

Tags: magento, import

There seems to be no solid consensus on this topic.  There is one thread [on the Magento message board](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/28426/P75/) which gives all kinds of variations and approaches, none of which work for me and none of which explain what should be done in this process.

From what I can tell, you need to simulate the steps of an order being created on the website, i.e. add products to a 'cart', add a shipping and billing address, add a shipping method, add a payment method and 'checkout'.

Can someone please explain exactly these steps, and show the lines of code that are responsible for executing the steps.

Also, I've seen reference in the message board code examples of a 'cart' and a 'quote'.  Please explain the difference (or similarities) between the 2.

Comment: I asked a valid question.  Why would you bother wasting your time posting crap this?  And who the hell down voted my question????

Comment: My point was that someone would have to write the equivalent of a blog article to sufficiently answer everything you requested in your question.  Further, writing a single sentence really doesn't take up that much of my time.  On this site, a question generally shouldn't require an answer that takes more than 30 mins to write.

Comment: I answered half my question in 10 minutes of typing time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've sorted out the programming task.  It turns out you don't have to simulate 'adding to the cart' as other posts elsewhere suggest.  You can create the order object and the related objects and populate with data, its just not as straightforward as I'd like it to be.

Creating an order was best described by [this blog post](http://blog.magentoconnect.us/magento-create-order-programmatically/).

I've copied the code here:

```
$id=1; // get Customer Id
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);

$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
$reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
  ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
  ->setStoreId($storeId)
  ->setQuoteId(0)
  ->setGlobal_currency_code('USD')
  ->setBase_currency_code('USD')
  ->setStore_currency_code('USD')
  ->setOrder_currency_code('USD');

// set Customer data
$order->setCustomer_email($customer->getEmail())
  ->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
  ->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
  ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
  ->setCustomer_is_guest(0)
  ->setCustomer($customer);

// set Billing Address
$billing = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
  ->setStoreId($storeId)
  ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
  ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
  ->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultBilling())
  ->setCustomer_address_id($billing->getEntityId())
  ->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
  ->setFirstname($billing->getFirstname())
  ->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
  ->setLastname($billing->getLastname())
  ->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
  ->setCompany($billing->getCompany())
  ->setStreet($billing->getStreet())
  ->setCity($billing->getCity())
  ->setCountry_id($billing->getCountryId())
  ->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
  ->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
  ->setPostcode($billing->getPostcode())
  ->setTelephone($billing->getTelephone())
  ->setFax($billing->getFax());
$order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

$shipping = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
  ->setStoreId($storeId)
  ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
  ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
  ->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultShipping())
  ->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
  ->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
  ->setFirstname($shipping->getFirstname())
  ->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
  ->setLastname($shipping->getLastname())
  ->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
  ->setCompany($shipping->getCompany())
  ->setStreet($shipping->getStreet())
  ->setCity($shipping->getCity())
  ->setCountry_id($shipping->getCountryId())
  ->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
  ->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
  ->setPostcode($shipping->getPostcode())
  ->setTelephone($shipping->getTelephone())
->setFax($shipping->getFax());

$order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
  ->setShipping_method('flatrate_flatrate')
  ->setShippingDescription($this->getCarrierName('flatrate'));

$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
  ->setStoreId($storeId)
  ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
  ->setMethod('purchaseorder')
  ->setPo_number(' - ');
$order->setPayment($orderPayment);

// let say, we have 2 products
$subTotal = 0;
  $products = array(
  '1001' => array(
  'qty' => 1
  ),
  '1002' ->array(
  'qty' => 3
  ),
);
foreach ($products as $productId=>$product) {
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
  $rowTotal = $_product->getPrice() * $product['qty'];
  $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setQuoteItemId(0)
    ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
    ->setProductId($productId)
    ->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
    ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
    ->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['rqty'])
    ->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
    ->setName($_product->getName())
    ->setSku($_product->getSku())
    ->setPrice($_product->getPrice())
    ->setBasePrice($_product->getPrice())
    ->setOriginalPrice($_product->getPrice())
    ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
    ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);

  $subTotal += $rowTotal;
  $order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$order->setSubtotal($subTotal)
  ->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
  ->setGrandTotal($subTotal)
  ->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal);

$transaction->addObject($order);
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
$transaction->save();
```

I still have not gotten an understanding of the distinction between a cart and quote is.